# Merge complex array php

Tags: php, array-merge

I have a site developed in php (codeigniter) and I want to merge some array with same structure.
This is the constructor of my array:

```
$first = array();
$first['hotel'] = array();
$first['room'] = array();
$first['amenities'] = array();

/*
Insert data into $first array
*/

$second = array();
$second['hotel'] = array();
$second['room'] = array();
$second['amenities'] = array();

/*
Insert data into $second array
*/
```

After insert data I want to merge this array but the problem is that I have subarray inside it and I want to create a unique array like that:

```
$total = array();
$total['hotel'] = array();
$total['room'] = array();
$total['amenities'] = array();
```

This is the try to merge:

```
$total = array_merge((array)$first, (array)$second);
```

In this array I have only the $second array why?

Comment: I'm confused about the desired output your looking for

Comment: The desired output is an array like first r second but with two arrays merged @SamuelCook

Comment: Could you be looking for [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)?

Comment: Yes the solution is array_mege_recursive! @complex857 I thought that array_merge can do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the recursive version of `array_merge` called [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).

Comment: I had to use array_replace_recursive instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way of doing it, you just have to do something like:

```
<?php
$first = array();
$first['hotel'] = array('hello');
$first['room'] = array();
$first['amenities'] = array();

/*
Insert data into $first array
*/

$second = array();
$second['hotel'] = array('world');
$second['room'] = array();
$second['amenities'] = array();

$merged = array();
foreach( $first as $key => $value )
{
    $merged[$key] = array_merge( $value, $second[$key] );
}

print_r( $merged );
```

Comment: Why overwrite `$first` when you can't be sure it won't be needed later on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge) doesn't do what you think it does: "If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one." Try this:

```
function merge_subarrays ($first, $second)
  $result = array();
  foreach (array_keys($first) as $key) {
    $result[$key] = array_merge($first[$key], $second[$key]);
  };
  return $result;
};
```

Then call it as:

```
$total = merge_subarrays($first, $second);
```

and, if I've correctly understood your question, `$total` will contain the result you're looking for.